# glmnet Python Library Load Issue

Tags: python, glmnet

I am currently trying to follow the [glmnet_python vignette](https://glmnet-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/glmnet_vignette.html) but keep running into the error:

```
# call glmnet
fit = glmnet(x = x.copy(), y = y.copy(), family = 'gaussian', \
                    weights = wts, \
                    alpha = 0.2, nlambda = 20
                    )

OSError: dlopen(/Users/my_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/glmnet_python/GLMnet.so, 6): image not found
```

I am using Python 3.6 and above and am working on a macOS Big Sur and have tried [this trick](https://github.com/bbalasub1/glmnet_python/issues/13) from the Github page but have had no luck. Is there any clear fix to this? I've tried running the code on Google Colab but get the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-2da1d7aed75d> in <module>()
----> 1 import glmnet_python
      2 from glmnet import glmnet

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/glmnet_python/cvglmnet.py in <module>()
    200 from glmnetPredict import glmnetPredict
    201 import scipy
--> 202 from glmnet import glmnet
    203 from cvelnet import cvelnet
    204 from cvlognet import cvlognet

ImportError: cannot import name 'glmnet' from 'glmnet' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/glmnet/__init__.py)
```

before even getting to the next stages of the vignette. Has anyone encountered this issue or know how to fix it?

Thanks.